# Error in storm-starter: Could not find artifact 0.10.0-SNAPSHOT in clojars

Tags: apache-storm

I cloned storm-starter from https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter, then went to build my jar locally using "mvn clean install -DskipTests=true"

Here's the error I got:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project storm-starter: Could not resolve depen
dencies for project org.apache.storm:storm-starter:jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT: Could no
t find artifact org.apache.storm:storm-core:jar:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT in clojars (http
s://clojars.org/repo/) -> [Help 1]
```

Maybe I'm looking at the wrong location, but I don't see "storm" listed at https://clojars.org/repo/org/apache/

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to build development branch of storm-starter, which is build against Storm's current development branch (0.10.0-SNAPSHOT), so you have to build storm yourself:

> If you are using the latest development version of Storm, e.g. by having cloned the Storm git repository, then you must first perform a local build of Storm itself. Otherwise you will run into Maven errors such as "Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.storm:storm-starter:-SNAPSHOT".

Try [v0.9.3](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/v0.9.3/) instead, which is build against the latest stable Storm, and as such has it's dependencies [hosted in Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.storm%22).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the **top-level directory** of the Storm code repository

```
$ mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
```

This command will build Storm locally and install its jar files to your user's $HOME/.m2/repository/. When you run the Maven command to build and run storm-starter (see below), Maven will then be able to find the corresponding version of Storm in this local Maven repository at $HOME/.m2/repository.

https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter#getting-started